# To put lim over the arrow?

Tags: math-mode

I want to have the `N \to \infty` over the arrow like

[image]

**How can you have something over the arrow?**

Comment: there are a lot of options in amssymb and amsmath documentation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

assuming `amsmath`

```
\xrightarrow{ N \to \infty }
```

I like to make the arrow slightly longer using, say,

```
\xrightarrow{\: N \to \infty \: }
```

Answer (score 4):

If controlling the vertical space between the arrow and the overset is important, here's an approach, which uses an optional argument to control the gap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-10-15]
\newcommand\spaceoverxrightarrow[2][\stackgap]{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackon[#1]{\xrightarrow[\phantom{#2}]{}}%
  {\scriptscriptstyle #2}}}
\begin{document}
$\spaceoverxrightarrow{N\to\infty}$

$\spaceoverxrightarrow[0.3pt]{N\to\infty}$

$\spaceoverxrightarrow[5pt]{N\to\infty}$
\end{document}
```

[image]